Unable to receive all attributes from a MongoDB document
I am trying to fetch a document from a MongoDB collection. At the Db, I have this single document:

The issue i am facing is that I am unable to fetch the content array. In the fetched document, there is simply no such field. Please guide me what mistake i am making here?
This is the Schema i have for it:
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const ContentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { _id: false },
); 

const BlogSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      required: true,
    },
    heading: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paragraph: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    coverImagePath: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: [ContentSchema],
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

const BlogModel = models.blog || model("blog", BlogSchema);

export default BlogModel;


This is how i am fetching all the documents from this collection, (at the moment, there is only 1 document in the collection which i created manually.)
const blogsCollectionData = (await BlogModel.find({})) as BlogDocType[];

This is BlogDocType:
export type BlogDocType = {
  _id: ObjectId;
  createdAt: Date;
  paragraph: string;
  heading: string;
  coverImgPath: string;
  content: BlogContentDoc[];
};
export type BlogContentDoc = {
  type: string;
  _id: ObjectId;
};

But when i print the document, this is what i get:
[
  {
    createdAt: 1725884791793,
    _id: new ObjectId('66dbba46cd201551710e0499'),
    heading: 'Some of my data',
    coverImagePath: 'public/blogImages/001.png',
    createdAT: 2000-12-31T19:00:00.000Z,
    paragraph: 'This is a test paragraph'
  }
]

I have tried to fully match the Schema with the Database document but i cant figure out why it does not fetch the content array. I have also reviwed the Datatypes of both sides to make sure that they match but still not the required result.

not sure if this is the case, but I've been struggling with the same problem and the solution was to use embedding instead of referencing.


import mongoose from "mongoose";
//instead of using the Model use the schema here
import {queueSchema} from "./QueueModel";

const tournamentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
   name: {type: String, required: true},
   categories: [{type: String, required: true}],
   description: {type: String},
   //found that this is called embedding
   queues: [queueSchema]
   // queues: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "QueueModel"}]
  },
  {collection: "tournaments"}
)



